# Run a create action from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

Here is my problem :
I have a post controller with the action create. I would like that when a new post is created then I have as well an Activity that is created as well that will contain all informations about the post, ...
For now i'm just creating and saving this activity inside the PostController create action but I would like to be able to launch the create action of the Activity Controller so that everything is the right place - but is it the way I should do that ? Is there a conceptual problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are supposed to mediate the communication between views and models.

So, if you want to keep your code [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), create (for example) a class method in `Activity` class that'll do what you want and then call it from both `PostController#create` and `ActivityController#create`.

This is far better than trying to fire a controller method (which would semantically mean another request from the client).

Comment: Right so you mean inside the model/activity.rb file ? Will I be able to do something like "self.post_id = ..." and "self.save" ?

Comment: @DavidFabreguette: if it's an instance method - yes.